# Items not being added to array?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

So this should be super simple, but I have no idea whats wrong.

```
    var imageColors = [];

    $('.portfolio-image').each(function(index, el) {
        RGBaster.colors(this, {
          success: function(payload) {
            console.log(payload.dominant);
            imageColors.push(payload.dominant);
          }
        });
    });

    $('.portfolio-title').each(function(index, el) {
        $(this).css('color', 'imageColors[index]');
    });

});
```

So the code above has an array which should store colors from a set of images. Then we cycle through some text and set the text color to be the dominant color from each image in the order they are visible.

Anyways, the problem is no matter how I "add" something the imageColors array, nothing is in it. When I run a console.log of the length of the array it's always 0. So can someone explain why nothing is being added?

Comment: Please make working fiddle and let us know

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you have a `success` callback passed to `colors` plugin, it looks like a async method that means when the second each block is executed the array may not be filled with the desired data.

One solution here is to set the color css inside the callback like

```
var imageColors = [];
var $titles = $('.portfolio-title');
$('.portfolio-image').each(function (index, el) {
    RGBaster.colors(this, {
        success: function (payload) {
            imageColors.push(payload.dominant);
            $titles.eq(index).css('color', payload.dominant);
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: This works, it must've been the async issue. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

**Take off String value**

```
$.each(imageColors, function(index, el) {
    $('.portfolio-title').css('color', imageColors[index]);
});
```

ERROR `'imageColors[index]'` CORRECTION `imageColors[index]`

Comment: Changed it, no color changes though. The output of the payload.dominant is rgb(0,0,0) for example so it should work just going there right? Also the length still says zero. If I run console.log(imageColors.length) before I try to change the color of the text it logs 0 still.

Comment: The problem is that nothing is being added to the array. It has nothing to do with how the color is being set.

Answer (score -1):

You have to go with this

```
$('.portfolio-title').each(function(index, el) {
    $(this).css('color', imageColors[index]); \\ remove single quote
});
```